# Why does the arrow function (line 35) return undefined?

Tags: arrow-functions

Why does the function (line 30) return expected values ("my name is Pumpkin Latte and I cost $5") but the arrow function (line 35) return undefined for this.name and this.price ("my name is Codepen and I cost undefined")?

https://codepen.io/mikntj/pen/xxrOEdE?editors=0011

```
function Latte (name) {
  this.name = name
  this.price = "$5"
}


function Cappucino (name) {
  this.name = name
  this.price = "$6"
}



function CoffeeFactory (name, price) {
  this.create = (name, price) => {
    switch(price)  {
     
     case 1:
       return new Latte(name);
       break;
       
     case 2:
        return new Cappucino(name);
        break;
     }        
  }
}


// function say () 
// {
//   console.log("my name is " + this.name + " and I cost " +this.price)
// }

const say = () => {
  console.log("my name is " + this.name + " and I cost " +this.price)
}
        

const coffeeFactory = new CoffeeFactory()
const coffees = []


coffees.push(coffeeFactory.create("Pumpkin Latte", 1))
coffees.push(coffeeFactory.create("Double Cappucino", 2))


     
coffees.forEach( cof => {
  say.call(cof)
})
```

Comment: Not sure if this works out, since you used say.call(cof), but: Once you declare a function, the `this` keyword will refer to the function itself given the function was given a name. Hence, you've basically said that on line 35, `this` should refer to `const say`. Try console.log(this) in your function to see what it resolves to.

Comment: @mikntj - Why do you say _return undefined for this.name_ when `this.name` obviously is _Codepen_?